# ErrorDocument in httpd.conf not working

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, errordocument

I want to use custom error file for 403 but apache just seems to ignore the directive `ErrorDocument` and just gives me the default error document. Here's the beginning of my `httpd.conf`

```
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"

Listen 80

ErrorDocument 403 "/403.html" 
ErrorDocument 404 "/403.html"
```

I just added `404` to see if it would work, it didn't. The file `403.html` exists in`C:\xampp\apache\403.html`

I tried moving the `ErrorDocument` directive further down in the configuration file, where comments describing `ErrorDocument` directive start but the result was the same.

I do not have `ErrorDocument` directives in any `.htaccess` files in folders that I'm testing.

Can you please tell me why apache is ignoring me?

## EDIT

Just to be sure I will mention the way I'm testing this. I have a `.htaccess` file in `C:\xampp\htdocs` with the following contents

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Deny from all
```

The purpose of which is to deny access to all subfolders and files that don't explicitly allow it, and then I'm just sending a request to my public IP to get access denied.

Comment: Does it work when you use `ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/403.html`. [This post may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976772/errordocument-404-404-php-is-not-working-in-htaccess-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place to look in case of any error are the `logs/error.log` and `logs/access.log` logfiles of your apache installation.

As the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument states, this directive is relative to the `DocumentRoot` of your current host configuration. 
You are not using a default Apache HTTPD but instead the preconfigured Apachefriends XAMPP which has some specialties e.g. the standard `httpd.conf` coming with XAMPP references the `ErrorDocument`s via

```
# Multi-language error messages
Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
```

In the default `httpd.conf` your `DocumentRoot` is `C:\apache\htdocs` so with your above mentioned changes (namely `ErrorDocument 403 "/403.html"`) in your `httpd.conf`, you will have to place those files into `C:\xampp\htdocs\403.html`.

As an aside it is usually a good idea to separate your custom configuration by adding an `Include conf/my-custom.conf` to `httpd.conf` and adding your config in there.

Comment: I moved the file to `C:\xampp\htdocs\403.html` and restarted apache, just in case, but I'm still getting the default error document. Thanks for the suggestion for the separate configuration file, that's good advice!

Comment: After moving the file, did you verify that http://127.0.0.1/403.html returns your HTML file? The next step would be to set the `ErrorDocument` directive inside the `.htaccess` file. If this works fine, the problem is that your modified `ErrorDocument` directive inside your httpd.conf doesn't apply to the `htdocs` folder.

Comment: It's very common that a directive is overwritten by another directive e.g. in a more specific scope or a position later in the loading phase. That's why I suggested to have a separate configuration file e.g. with a `<Virtualhost>` or a `<Directory>` directive. That's where you usually put the config you have got in your `.htaccess` file now. What's the result when you put the `ErrorDocument` directive into your `.htacess`?