# getting 404 error on when accessing sub folders of my website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am running a website `http://dudesrgamerz.com` and getting a 404 error when accessing subfolder of my website (I am running the second script in a subfolder called `/apps/`). `/apps/index.php` is working fine but when accessing `/apps/detail/zello-ptt-walkie-talkie?appid=com.loudtalks` it's not working; it's returning 404 error page.

Here is `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Uncomment (remove # ONLY NOT ##) line below if installed in folder and add folder name after /
## Example: Script is installed in /public_html/folder/ then it should be: Rewritebase /folder/
## Then the files below should be (add slash to all): /index.php?action=$1
## Uncomment the code below to Use PHP 5.4
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteEngine On

## Uncomment the following line to use the multi-domain feature
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourseconddomain\.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourfirstdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Rewritebase /
## Admin Panel
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

## Application Handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?a=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

## Error 404 ##
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?a=404
```

Comment: i think you should place `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?a=404` in .htaccess at top location

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file? What do you want to happen when your access that URL? Do you have other scripts that route URLs? What about `/index.php` in the document root?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit The location of the `ErrorDocument` directive in the `.htaccess` file doesn't actually matter, but it would be more logical (and easier to read) if it was at the top.

Comment: @prince jay ohk but what you are trying to access if its not a file then this htaccess take your control to index.php not the 404 and if its there then it will be served. nothing more than that. also try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976772/errordocument-404-404-php-is-not-working-in-htaccess-file-in-php

Comment: @DhavalPurohit  thanks for the reply i have placed the code in the .htaccess but the problem still there. please check this  [link](http://dudesrgamerz.com/apps/) .

I am running a sub script in a sub folder called **(apps)**, the problem is I am getting 404 error page when trying to access another page of the script.

Comment: do you have any routes named `apps/` in your laravel routes.php ?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit no . i have decided to use deferent hosting provider for this subdomain **apps.dudesrgamer.com** . is that okay?  how can I do that ? is there any tutorial?

Comment: you can do this in your cpanel
add subdomain and point it to your apps directory
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains

Comment: @DhavalPurohit  thank you very much, problem solved!

Comment: you are welcome @PrinceJay