# Xampp Error "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Hi I am trying out apache htaccess for my site(not wordpress). I want to make custom 404 error so I add following in `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

My file structure is

```
/htdocs
       /some-dir
                /.htaccess
                /404.php
```

while I accessing any random URL I get the error:

> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ErrorDocument 404 /404.php is not working in .htaccess file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976772/errordocument-404-404-php-is-not-working-in-htaccess-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
> ```

The `ErrorDocument` directive takes a document root-relative URL-path, so from your file structure this should presumably be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /some-dir/404.php
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument